# does rsync guarantee integrity of the files transferred assuming it finishes?

Tags: linux, md5, rsync

assuming rsync finishes, does it guarantee the integrity of the files transferred?  or should I compute md5sums to further check on all files?

Comment: The same doubts you have for rsync are also valid against md5.

Comment: Is your concern is that a file might be modified while `rsync(1)` (or `md5sum(1)`) is processing that file?

Comment: You can use `rsync -c` to force it to actually compute checksums on every file, rather than just going off timestamps. That'll slow it down, of course, so maybe you only want to do that occasionally...

Comment: no file will be modified while rsync, according to man page rsync does checksum before and after transfer a while if it decides to transfer a while, so I guess it's safe